# Why a PowerShell command in a host is not returning the same thing as in the PowerShell console?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am developing a Windows user management utility in VB.Net Winforms hosting PowerShell. I successfully execute the required command to set the executionpolicy for the process, the problem arises when I try and execute "Get-LocalUser" with no parameters. In the PowerShell Console on my Windows 10 Anniversary Update machine it returns the Builtin Administrator Account, Guest and my personal account. Under my application I get no objects returned from Invoke(), no errors or  warnings either. What can I try to figure this issue out?

My code is:

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-LocalUser")
For Each user As PSObject In ps.Invoke()
    MainListView.Items.Add(user.Properties("Name").ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Check ps.Streams.Error and ps.HadErrors. Invoke is unlikely to throw an exception of its own (because PS raising errors is not exceptional).

Comment: I believe you can use this as an alternate.  get-ciminstance win32_useraccount

Comment: Chris Dent: ps.HadErrors returns False and ps.Streams.Error.Count returns 0. Randy Chuman: I was hoping to be able to use PowerShell to modify the user accounts as well as I notice your command comes back with extra info. I also get 0 users returned and no errors using  get-ciminstance win32_useraccount